Django allauth facebook login redirects to signup page
I have problem with logging to my app via Facebook. When I'm passing through facebook login form it redirect me to /accounts/social/signup/#= page in my app.
My settings:
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "apps.users.adapter.MyAccountAdapter"
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "apps.users.adapter.MySocialAccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = False

django-allauth version is 0.41.0 (it's old because it's legacy code)
Interestingly, on test environment django-allauth does not redirect me (the same facebook client and secret and the same config) to signup page.
What may cause the same configuration to work differently in different environments? I've tried with different config but still problem is the same. I don't want to be redirected to signup page.
